# Call custom logger after initializing in a file in all other files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

I have created a `logger.py` file like so:

```
import logging

Log_Format = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"

log_file = get_log_filename()

def setup_logger(name, log_file, level=logging.INFO):
    handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, mode="a")
    handler.setFormatter(Log_Format)
    handler.setLevel(level)

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger


logger = setup_logger("Logger", log_file)
```

Then I have multiple files where I have to use logging. So I call them like this:

**file1.py**
**file2.py**
**file3.py**

```
from logger import logger
logger.info('This is a log info')
```

The whole app is called by calling one file like so: `python3 main_file.py`

**main_file.py**

```
from logger import logger

from file1 import func1
from file2 import func2
from file3 import func3

logger.info("This log is in the main file")
```

In the main file there is no `main` function. It is just a python script which is executed line by line.
My problem is that there are no logs being saved in the file or shown in the console. What am I doing wrong here? How to rectify this?

But if I write this in `main_file.py`

```
Log_Format = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"

log_file = get_log_filename()

logging.basicConfig(
    filename=log_file,
    filemode="a",
    format=Log_Format,
    level=logging.INFO,
)


logger = logging.getLogger("Logger")
```

Then import it in other files like so:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("Logger")
```

Then the above code works. But I want to intialize like I have said in the first example. Can I do it?

Comment: What does `get_log_filename()` return? When I hardcoded `log_file = "testlog.txt"` and fixed `handler.setFormatter(Log_Format)` (it needs to be `handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt=Log_Format))`), it worked for me.

Comment: `get_log_filename()` returns a string. It is basically a wrapper for `os.path.join()`.

Comment: It could be the source of the bug if it puts the file in an unexpected place and you just aren't looking in the right place.

Comment: The problem was here, like u said in the comment, `handler.setFormatter(Log_Format)`. Your code fixed it. Thanks.